# Eclipse Errors/Warnings ignore assert in unused variable analysis

Tags: java, eclipse, static-analysis, findbugs, unused-variables

I have had 'hidden' bugs due to Eclipse not reporting 'unused' variables because they were used in an assertion (precondition), for example:

```
public void method(final String text, ...other parameters) {
  assert StringUtils.isNotBlank(text);
  ...
  // The text variable is never used in the method.
  // If Eclipse had reported the variable as 'unused' I would have noticed that something is wrong with the code.
  ...
}
```

I would like to tell Eclipse to ignore assertions when checking for unused variables. I doubt anyone would pass a parameter to only run an assertion on it...
Also let me know if FindBugs or another tool can do this.

Comment: FindBugs might be able to do this if you tell the compiler to leave out assertions in the byte code. Then FindBugs should see that the variable is unused. Unless of course the compiler removes the unused variable from the bytecode as well. (Which I'd expect.) Checkstyle and PMD do not have an "Ignore Assertions" flag afaik.

Comment: You can use @NonNull annotation in your case to avoid assert http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-using_null_annotations.htm?cp=1_3_9_0

Comment: Following up on Thomas' answer. There is no switch to remove assertions from the bytecode. Here's how to do it:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html#usage-adv-removing

Comment: @Barett thanks, this may be a solution to find those issues from time to time.

Comment: @KonstantinZaitsev Using the `@NonNull` annotation will not solve this issue, I am talking about any possible assertion, not just about `assert != null` (isNotBlank is doing more than checking for nullity)

Comment: Not a solution, but a work-around: keep your assertion in your `method` method and, after that, call a `unsafeMethod` that accepts the same arguments and has no assertions. You'll get the warning there

Answer (score 1):

Here is my own attempt at solving this with a 'brute' solution:

- Write a script that makes a copy of your source code and removes all
  assertions from it
- Inspect that assert less copy as you would inspect the original
- Manually remove variables used only
  in asserts from the original source code

Note that there is a similar problem with JavaDoc linked variables... if a variable is mentioned in the JavaDoc it will be considered as used (by Eclipse and maybe other IDE).

Comment: In Eclipse there is a preference to warn on unused parameters even if they have javadocs.